# Angular 10: How to load user information back on page refresh

Tags: angular

I have an angular app that loads user related information (user's favorites, selected items etc) through separate API call when user logs in.

It's a simple GET API call & in login component, I redirect user to dashboard once the call to this API is completed.

The result of this API is used on dashboard page. When user refresh the dashboard page, the object is null. I tried to call the API is app component ng oninit method, but the code accessing object in dashboard component is execute before completing this API.

How can I wait for the API call to complete?

Comment: Try to use it as an observable and subscribe to it on the template using the async pipe.
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: you can use resolver in angular so it wont render the page until you resolver complete

Comment: @Pradeep Thanks, I was able to make it work with Route Resolver

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to ensure that the content is presented only after the request has been successfully completed. You can complete using the `*ngIf` directive. There're two ways to do that:

### Without `async` pipe.

template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userData">
    <!-- Your dashboard code here -->
</ng-content>
```

controller:

```
userData?: any;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.userDataService.get().subscribe(res => {
        this.userData = res;
    });
}
```

### With `async` pipe.

template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userData$ | async">
    <!-- Your dashboard code here -->
</ng-content>
```

controller:

```
userData$?: Observable<any>;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.userData$ = this.userDataService.get();
}
```

Comment: So, I am not exactly using the object in html. But, it is used in many components. For instance, one of the page (after login), on ngOnInit loads list of tasks. & userData object contains favorite task id. Can I make this user object a BehaviorSubject? How can I go about that?

Comment: Basically, what I should be able to do is, if the user object has value ( when user navigates through login screen it has value) then it should be immediately able to use it. if not (if user is doing F5, object is still loading) wait for the object to load.